# Multiple TableView Tables on single pane fail (JavaFX)

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have to build a page within a java application containing 4 tables (we've chose to use javaFX to use, therefore we're using TableView tables)

There is a problem though. Using multiple tables on 1 pane doesnt seem succesfull. Here you can see the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1H2j.png (I cannot post images yet..)

As you can see it only shows 1 player (a goalkeeper) instead of all the desired players. Whenever i disable all tables but one it shows the desired information.

You can find my code via this link: http://pastebin.com/5AAchCKh

Comment: You can't use the same columns in multiple tables.

Comment: @James so i have to setup a set of columns for each individual table?

Comment: I believe so. I haven't tried "re-using" columns between multiple tables the way you do it here, but I think you'd end up violating the "nodes may only appear once in the scene graph" rule.

Comment: For example, imagine the user resizes the "name" column in one of the tables, but not in the other. What would `name.getWidth()` give you?

Comment: The scene graph doesn't complain about the same node reused, so it runs, but as I could test, showing the last data in all the table views. In fact, all the tables sharing the same column are resized at the same time when you resize one column.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. `TableColumn` is not a `Node`, and each table view will create its own cells. All the tables just share the same set of properties (width, data, etc) for the shared columns. Bad things (well, even worse things) probably happen if you set a `graphic` on the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reuse the `TableColumn` objects.

This fails:

```
tableTeamField.getColumns().addAll(name,position,age,worth,shooting,...);
tableSelectionField.getColumns().addAll(name,position,age,worth,shooting,...);
```

When the data is applied to the tables, only the data from the last table is shown in all of them. Basically, you are applying to the sane column different values: only the last one will be visible.

So you need to create different `TableColumn`s for each `TableView`. This will work:

```
tableTeamField.getColumns().addAll(name1,position1,age1,worth1,shooting1,...);
tableSelectionField.getColumns().addAll(name2,position2,age2,worth2,shooting2,...);
```